# INSERT+SELECT with a unique key

Tags: sql-server

The following T-SQL statement does not work because `[key]` has to be unique and the `MAX` call in the `SELECT` statement only seems to be called once. In other words it is only incrementing the key value once and and trying to insert that value over and over. Does anyone have a solution?

```
INSERT INTO [searchOC].[dbo].[searchTable]
([key],
 dataVaultType,
 dataVaultKey,
 searchTerm)
SELECT (SELECT MAX([key]) + 1 FROM [searchOC].[dbo].[searchTable]) AS [key]
  ,'PERSON' as dataVaultType
  ,[student_id] as dataVaultKey
  ,[email] as searchTerm
FROM [JACOB].[myoc4Data].[dbo].[users]
WHERE [email] != '' AND [active] = '1'
AND [student_id] IN (SELECT [userID] FROM [JACOB].[myoc4Data].[dbo].[userRoles] 
WHERE ([role] = 'STUDENT' OR [role] = 'FACUTLY' OR [role] = 'STAFF'))
```

Comment: Can the key be a seeded identity?  If so, then you don't have to insert the key field as it will automatically increment.

Comment: Why not use `IDENTITY`? This would solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe the condition: WHERE [email] != '' AND [active] = '1' ruins it. It doesnt really return the max of the table, only the max if the where condition..

Comment: It is virtually alawys a bad idea to seaerch for the max value and then choose one. You are almost guaranteed to race conditions and then data integrity problems later If you don't explicitly use transactions and try catch blocks when running inserts to both parent and child tables. Why is an autogenrated key not acceptable?

Comment: As @GregOks alluded to it's not going to work even if it was right, unless active default's to one and searchitem is always an empty string. Even if you fixed that you'd need a table lock, change it a bit and you'd have to do select max every insert and use a cursor or a while loop. This is just asking for it.

Comment: If you have to go with this implementation Select the max key value into a variable and then use Row_Number() Over (Order By [Pick a column]) + @variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make the key column an IDENTITY column that would probably be the easiest. That allows SQL Server to generate incremental values.

Alternatively, if you are definite about finding your own way to generate the key then a blog post I wrote last month may help. Although it uses a composite key, it shows you what you need to do to stop the issue with inserting multiple rows in a single INSERT statement safely generating a new value for each new row and it is also safe across many simultaneous writers (which many examples don't deal with)

http://colinmackay.co.uk/2012/12/29/composite-primary-keys-including-identity-like-column/

Incidentally, the reason that you get the same value for MAX(Key) on each row in your SELECT is that this happens at the time the table is read from. So for all the rows that the SELECT statement returns the MAX(key) will always be the same. Unless you add some sort of GROUP BY clause for any SELECT statement any MAX(columnName) function will return the same value for each row returned.

Also, all aggregate functions are deterministic, so for each equivalent set of input it will always have the same output. So if your set of keys was 1, 5, 9 then it will always return 9.